# Time measuring insertion & mergesort

Tags: java, mergesort

I have a problem that i cant solve on my own because i cant find the problem and i dont know where to look.
Im lookin to measuring my merge and insertionsort algorithms. Im pretty sure its no problem with my algorithms, they work as the should, but the thing thats off is the value of the measured time. All the test have almost identical values, and the value ends with E14 ?
Have i done something wrong with the convertion from nano time to sec or ms?
Take a look.

My results is being displayed like this:

```
Merge Sort integer 
Before:[97, 25, 91, 95, 60, 55, 59, 73, 75, 80]
After: [25, 55, 59, 60, 73, 75, 80, 91, 95, 97]
Measured time: 3.213631365062379E14 seconds


import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

import jv222dp_assign3.SortingAlgorithms;

public class AlgorithmMeasure {

    private static int intSize = 10;
    private static int[] arr = new int[intSize];
    private static String[] sArr = new String[10];
    private static Random random = new Random();

    public static String randomString(){
        char[] chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
            sb.append(c);
        }
        String output = sb.toString();

        return output;
    }

    public static int randomInteger(){

        int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
            temp = random.nextInt(arr.length*10);
        }

        return temp;
    }

    public static double getIntSelectionSortTime(){

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            arr[i] = randomInteger();
        }

        System.out.println("Before:"+Arrays.toString(arr));
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        int[] temp = SortingAlgorithms.insertionSort(arr);
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("After: "+Arrays.toString(temp));
        double sec = (double) endTime - startTime/1000000000.0;

        return sec;
    }

    public static double getStringSelectionSortTime(){

        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j ++){
            sArr[j] = randomString();
        }

        System.out.println("Before: "+Arrays.toString(sArr));
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        String[] temp = SortingAlgorithms.insertionSort(sArr);
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        double sec2 = (double) endTime - startTime/1000000000.0;

        System.out.println("After: "+Arrays.toString(temp));

        return sec2;
    }

    public static double getIntMergeSortTime(){

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            arr[i] = randomInteger();
        }

        System.out.println("Before:"+Arrays.toString(arr));
        long startTime2 = System.nanoTime();
        int[] temp = SortingAlgorithms.insertionSort(arr);
        long endTime2 = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("After: "+Arrays.toString(temp));
        double sec2 = (double) endTime2 - startTime2/1000000000.0;

        return sec2;
    }

    public static double getStringMergeSortTime(){

        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j ++){
            sArr[j] = randomString();
        }

        System.out.println("Before: "+Arrays.toString(sArr));
        long startTime2 = System.nanoTime();
        String[] temp = SortingAlgorithms.insertionSort(sArr);
        long endTime2 = System.nanoTime();
        double sec3 = (double) endTime2 - startTime2/1000000000.0;

        System.out.println("After: "+Arrays.toString(temp));

        return sec3;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Selection Sort integer ");
        System.out.println("Measured time: "+getIntSelectionSortTime()+" seconds");
        System.out.println("Selection Sort string ");
        System.out.println("Measured time: "+getStringSelectionSortTime()+" seconds");
        System.out.println("Merge Sort integer ");
        System.out.println("Measured time: "+getIntMergeSortTime()+" seconds");
        System.out.println("Merge Sort string ");
        System.out.println("Measured time: "+getStringMergeSortTime()+" seconds");
    }

}
```

Comment: You need parens around ((double) endTime - startTime), otherwise you're dividing startTime by 1000000000.0 before subtracting.

Comment: Ahaa. Of course ::))
But now i get this : 2.6086E-5 seconds? ? 
And the mergesort : 1.3256E-5 seconds? 

And this is only 1 array i send throught the algorithms..

Comment: Keep in mind those arrays from your post above are very small and will be sorted in small fractions of a second. You might want to generate a large array (as in thousands of numbers) of random numbers and measure sorting that.

Comment: Okey. THis is a assignment, and we are supposed to this:  How many strings and integers can be sorted in 1 second using these four algorithms?(merge integers/strings, insertionsort(int, strings))

So if im right? I need to generaete a undefined loop that sends/create new arrays while the time < 1 second?= (in this case 1 000 000 000 nano seconds? Or how ? :D Would appreiceate some help ;:D

Comment: Edit: nevermind, yes that approach should work. Just keep increasing the size of the array till you hit a 1 second sort time. Sorry for all the edits

Comment: No problem.  I have just realized all the code i have done is to much for this assignment just because the teacher only is intrested in the numbers, we are going to write a smal report on the result to. BUt anyway i have learned alot :)